# create Macro in VBA with colors if the value of the cell is greater than 100, the macro will change background color of the cell to blue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I create a macro in VBA that accomplishes the following: For the active cell, if the value of the cell is greater than a number, the macro will change background color of the cell .